# Скрипты на Unity

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здраствуйте, это снова я с Unity. Есть проблема. Я не могу вставить скрипт во вкладку main camera и в другие вкладки. Вылезает это оповещение обозначенное красной рамкой. Никаких ошибок в коде нет. Пытался закрывать код, потом вставлять. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажи что внутри скрипта написано

Comment: Файл должен назваться так же, как класс-наследник Monobehaviour

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Это как примерно должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя класса должно быть таким же, как имя файла. Надо переименовать `NewBehaviourScript` в `MainMenu`. Точно так же (`MainMenu` слитно) назвать файл